# How to pass props to a component when it's wrapped in a Higher Order Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hoc

I have the following code files and want to pass the props to a component wrapped inside a higher-order component. I need to pass props from the index page, but the components are wrapped inside two higher-order components. When I pass props to the component in index.js and console.log props in About.jsx it logs an empty object.

**index.js**

```
import { Header, Footer, Work, Skills, Testimonial, About } from "../container";

import { Navbar } from "../components";
import { client } from "../services/client";

export default function Home(props) {
  console.log(props.abouts);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Navbar />
      <Header />
      <About abouts={props.abouts} />
      <Work />
      <Skills />
      <Testimonial />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

/// I get the props from getStaticProps and I've tested the props, it actually fetches the data.

**About.jsx**

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { motion } from "framer-motion";
    import { Profile } from "./About.styled";
    import { urlFor, client } from "../../services/client";
    import { AppWrap, MotionWrap } from "../../wrapper";
    
    const About = (props) => {
      const [abouts, setAbouts] = useState([]);
    

// This useEffect is just for testing purposes, I need to get the data through props from index.js which gets it from getStaticProps()
      useEffect(() => {
        const query = "*[_type == 'abouts']";
        client.fetch(query).then((data) => setAbouts(data));
      }, []);
      console.log(props);
      return (
        <>
          <h2 className="head-text">
            I know that
            <span> Good Apps</span>
            <br />
            means
            <span> Good Business</span>
          </h2>
          <Profile className="app_profiles">
            {abouts.map((about, index) => (
              <motion.div
                whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
                whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
                transition={{ duration: 0.5, type: "tween" }}
                className="item"
                key={about.title + index}
              >
                <img src={urlFor(about.imgUrl)} alt={about.title} />
                <h2 className="bold-text" style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
                  {about.title}
                </h2>
                <p className="p-text" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
                  {about.description}
                </p>
              </motion.div>
            ))}
          </Profile>
        </>
      );
    };
    export default AppWrap(
      MotionWrap(About, "app__about"),
      "about",
      "app__whitebg"
    );
```

**motionWrap.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const MotionWrap = (Component, className, hello) =>
  function HOC() {
    return (
      <motion.div
        whileInView={{ y: [100, 50, 0], opacity: [0, 0, 1] }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
        className={`${className} app__flex`}
      >
        <Component hello={hello} />
      </motion.div>
    );
  };

export default MotionWrap;
```

**appWrap.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationDots, SocialMedia } from "../components";

const AppWrap = (Component, idName, classNames) =>
  function HOC() {
    return (
      <div id={idName} className={`app__container ${classNames}`}>
        {/* <SocialMedia /> */}
        <div className="app__wrapper app__flex">
          <Component />
          {/* <div className="copyright app__flex" style={copyrightStyle}>
            <p className="p-text">@2020 Nasyx</p>
            <p className="p-text">All rights reserved</p>
          </div> */}
        </div>
        <NavigationDots active={idName} />
      </div>
    );
  };
export default AppWrap;
```

***I want to pass props from index.js but when I console log props in About.jsx it is an empty object.***

/////////////// ** UPDATE **//////////
I managed to get the props by doing the following code changes

```
const MotionWrap = (Component, className) =>
  function HOC(...props) {}
```

** and **

```
const AppWrap = (Component, idName, classNames) =>
  function HOC(...props) {}
```

Reference:
[How to Wrap One React Component into Another](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-wrap-one-react-component-into-another)

Comment: Try to `console.log(props);` inside the `useEffect` of the `About` component

Comment: I did, It's undefined.

Comment: You may want to add the solution that worked for you as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing wrong in **index.js** file, you are passing **abouts** from **index.js** which you have assigned a value of **props.abouts** in the same file where it might be empty. Also you are not using **abouts** from **props** anywhere in your code but your are fetching the same via fetch which you are also not passing as **props** to any component!!!

Comment: Thanks, useEffect was just for testing purposes, I actually forgot to add the getStaticProps method to my question.

Comment: Updated it now.

Comment: Are you sure that abouts is a key in the props object itself which you get from getStaticProps()

Comment: Yes, 100%, I checked it with the console.log

Comment: what is the output of console log in index.js

Comment: console.log(props.abouts);                                                                                                   Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​

Comment: pass props here as well export default AppWrap(
      MotionWrap(About, "app__about"),
      "about",
      "app__whitebg"
    ); then here as well <Component hello={hello} />

Comment: You can not access the props outside the react component

Comment: i think you are not using proper About component in index.js as you are not exporting the about from within About.jsx as a component